# Function isn't working from radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have 3 radio buttons with values: `video`, `music` and `news`. I am calling the function from a radio button. Inside my function I have a `.onclick` function for the button to actually display the `iframes`.

I've tried using `onClick` but that won't work either.

#### HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="inner">
    <!--All contents in here-->
    <div id="header" align='center' style="margin:0 auto;">
      <label for='genre'>Type your genre</label>
      <input name="genre" id="genre" type="text" />
      <!-- <label for=='genreList'>Or</label>
      <select id='genreList' name='genreList' onchange="">
        <option id='video' selected='selected' value='video'>Comedy</option>
        <option id='music' value='music'>Misc</option>
        <option id='news' value='news'>Sport</option>
      </select>-->
      <input name="type" id='genre1' type="radio" value="video" checked="checked" onfocus="video();" />
      <label for='genre1'>Video</label>
      <input name="type" id='genre2' type="radio" value="music" onClick='alert("music");' />
      <label for='genre2'>Music</label>
      <input name="type" id='genre3' type="radio" value="news" />
      <label for='genre3'>News</label>
      <select id='numVid' name='numVid' onchange="">
        <option id='1' value='video'>1</option>
        <option id='2' value='1'>2</option>
        <option id='3' value='2'>3</option>
        <option id='4' value='3'>4</option>
        <option id='5' value='4'>5</option>
        <option id='6' value='5'>6</option>
        <option id='7' selected='selected' value='6'>7</option>
        <option id='8' value='7'>8</option>
        <option id='9' value='8'>9</option>
        <option id='10' value='9'>10</option>
        <option id='11' value='10'>11</option>
        <option id='12' value='11'>12</option>
      </select>
      <input type='button' id='displayAll' value='Get Videos' onClick='' />
    </div>
    <!--End Header-->
    <div id="videos"></div>
  </div>
  <!--End of inner-->
</body>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
function video() {
  //Input field (genre)
  var genre = document.getElementById('genre').value;
  genre = genre.toLowerCase();
  //Select menu genre choose.
  var genreOption = document.getElementById('genreList').value;

  //Embeding codes
  var embedComedy = new Array('QqhtaHY1yjQ', 'ptYA1k1JPeQ', 'mYHGPUqEOJY', 'mYHGPUqEOJY', 'VY4HObQw5Go', 'DiKCJaBUmRs', 'LAeUtlcETfc', 'xwGERoFtQoM', 'QqhtaHY1yjQ', 'VY4HObQw5Go', '3meqBxtY4dE');
  var embedMisc = new Array('hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU');
  var embedSport = new Array('cBJyo0tgLnw', 'uIBgWI_BTyM', 'Vs0QoCtvJmk');
  var embedDocumentary = new Array('PyQVjlE3zkU', 'bkprsIaoIv0', 'P4ynv-vRHKQ', 'tnpaaVB4XyA');

  //Holds embed codes when being looped (total 12).
  var videoEmbed = new Array(12); //Holds Embed Codes When Looped

  //Select menu value - number of videos.
  var numVideos = document.getElementById('numVideos').value;

  //Onclick display the embeded videos.
  document.getElementById('displayAll').onclick = function() {
    if (genre == 'comedy' || genre == 'comedi' || genre == 'com' || genre == 'funny' || genre == 'fun') {
      for (var i = 0; i < numVideos; i++) {
        videoEmbed[i] += "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/" + embedComedy[i] + "'" + "frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe><br /><hr width='90%'/>";
        document.getElementById('videos').innerHTML = videoEmbed;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try onchange event instead of onclick.

Comment: Why init ('displayAll').onclick in video() function ? You can init it in window.onload... I've added small demo in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function like triggerC() and call it inside the onclick on your radio button code and also when you call video() there are many gelELementByid which are null remove them. But main issue is your onclick function video() is working find but the code for rendering your videos document.getElementById('displayAll').onclick is not triggered. you have to explicitly call it like i have done with the function triggerC(). Hope this helps

```
function video() {
//Input field (genre)
console.log("hi")
var genre = document.getElementById('genre').value;
genre = genre.toLowerCase();
//Select menu genre choose.
//var genreOption = document.getElementById('genreList').value;

//Embeding codes
var embedComedy = new Array('QqhtaHY1yjQ', 'ptYA1k1JPeQ', 'mYHGPUqEOJY', 'mYHGPUqEOJY', 'VY4HObQw5Go', 'DiKCJaBUmRs', 'LAeUtlcETfc', 'xwGERoFtQoM', 'QqhtaHY1yjQ', 'VY4HObQw5Go', '3meqBxtY4dE');
var embedMisc = new Array('hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU', 'hC3VTgIPoGU');
var embedSport = new Array('cBJyo0tgLnw', 'uIBgWI_BTyM', 'Vs0QoCtvJmk');
var embedDocumentary = new Array('PyQVjlE3zkU', 'bkprsIaoIv0', 'P4ynv-vRHKQ', 'tnpaaVB4XyA');

//Holds embed codes when being looped (total 12).
var videoEmbed = new Array(12); //Holds Embed Codes When Looped

//Select menu value - number of videos.
var numVideos = document.getElementById('numVid').value;

//Onclick display the embeded videos.
function triggerC() {
    genre = 'video';
    if (genre == 'video' || genre == 'comedi' || genre == 'com' || genre == 'funny' || genre == 'fun') {
        console.log(numVideos);
        for (var i = 0; i < numVideos; i++) {
            console.log(numVideos);
            videoEmbed[i] += "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/" + embedComedy[i] + "'" + "frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe><br /><hr width='90%'/>";
            document.getElementById('videos').innerHTML = videoEmbed;
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById('displayAll').onclick = function() {
    triggerC()

}
triggerC()
```

}